# How do I view Rails audit records in my Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, console, audit

I’m using Rails 4.2.10 and the audited gem, defined in my Gemfile like so …

```
gem "audited-activerecord", "~> 4.0"
```

I have it activated in my models like so

```
class MyObject < ActiveRecord::Base
…
  audited
```

In the Rails console, how do I view specific Audit objects?  I tried this in my console …

```
> Audit.all
NameError: uninitialized constant Audit
    from (irb):2
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@cfs-web/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@cfs-web/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@cfs-web/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@cfs-web/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@cfs-web/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

But get the above errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't cross my mind to actually query the `audits` table and I had to look at the source code to see how to do it.

Generally this should work across versions:

```
Audited.audit_class.count # => 9999
```

With audited > 4.2.2, `Audit` got namespaced under `Audited` and it inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`, [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited/blob/v4.10.0/lib/audited/audit.rb) is the source code.

```
Audited::Audit.count # => 99999
```

Comment: Hmm, when I tried that, I got "NoMethodError: undefined method `count' for Audited::Audit:Module"

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check again. I'm using audited 4.8. Your `audited-activerecord` gem has audited locked at 4.2.2.